# How to find solutions to the gravitational potential metric h

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, gauge

I'm working on a problem in which a star of mass M1, radius R1 is surrounded by a thin shell of mass M2, , radius R2. I want to find the solutions to the gravitational potential h in the region in between the star and the shell and region outside both.

Can we assume the mass is stationary, and not too large, and thus use the analogous Poisson's equation (Laplacian of potential = 4*pi*G*rho)?

Or is there some physical reason that we should use the potential equation in the Hilbert gauge (d'Alembertian of tensor potential = 4*pi*G*(energy momentum tensor)/(c^2)?

My thinking is that Poisson's is totally appropriate for this simple situation of a stationary star with a shell mass around it.

Now, I don't see how to use Poisson's equation. I'm getting tripped up with how to consider the two masses. What if, for example, it's a very dense shell which is in fact more massive than the star. That would give a potential radially outward. How do I find a solution to the Laplacian?

Comment: Why aren't you just leveraging Birchoff's theorem?

Comment: As an addendum, it isn't too hard to prove Birchoff's theorem.  Just assume a spherically symmetric, static spacetime with a diagonal line element and vacuum matter distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the star and the shell are spherically symmetric, you can use the fact that the field of a symmetric distribution at any radius is the same as the field created by a mass point at the center that has the same mass as is closer to the center than the point of interest.  In particular, when you are between the star and the shell you can ignore the shell-it makes no field (though it does change the potential. )

Comment: What is the argument explaining that the shell makes no field but changes the potential? Thank you!

Comment: It changes the potential because as you integrate in from infinity there is a field until you come to the shell.  The potential from the shell at its surface is $\frac {-GM}R$. To show there is no field inside, take a point inside and integrate over the shell to find the field.  By symmetry the field must be radial, which gets you two of the integrals in spherical coordinates immediately.  You discover the field is zero, regardless of where you are inside the shell